# Node Mongoose: Partial search regular expression by any string with middle value

Tags: node.js, regex, mongodb, mongoose, mean-stack

I am newbie at node and regex. Looking to get regex for my node and mongoose app.

I am applying partial search to my application. Currently I am able to get result like following.
If i search by "jav"
Jav: true , Java: true, Javascript:true

Now i want to work for string with middle values too.
Ex. If i search for "ava"
then results should be same as above. Yes i want to keep case insensitivity(i) too

```
private getSearchResults(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
   var nameRegex = { "$regex": new RegExp('^' + req.params.name.toLowerCase(), 'i') };
 ........
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `'^' +` part:

```
new RegExp(req.params.name.toLowerCase(), 'i')
```

The `^` means that the name will be matched only against the start of a string.

Comment: Worked !! Thanks

Comment: "i" flag is for case insensitive, remove ".toLowerCase()"

Comment: @lefdilia I'm not sure if that won't have any impact in matching speed, given that MongoDB has (had?) issues with index use for case-insensitive queries. Generally speaking though, you're quite right.

Comment: @robertklep Is using req.params.XXX secure? I mean, it comes directly from the user. I think there needs to be at least some measure to only allow A-z, because **never trust user input**. Even only allowing only A-z I'm a bit afraid - you'll never know.

Comment: @Fusseldieb no, it's not secure. However, I don't know if the OP validates it beforehand to prevent possible issues. I also don't know if this is for a public website or not.  I understand what you're saying, but I felt that ultimately, this is a question about regular expressions, and not how to safely use them inside web apps.